# Mypy reports an incompatible supertype error with overridden method

Tags: python-3.x, types, mypy

Below is a simplified example of a problem I've encountered with `mypy`.
The `A.transform` method takes an iterable of objects, transforms each one (defined in the subclass `B`, and potentially other subclasses) and returns an iterable of transformed objects.

```
from typing import Iterable, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

class A:
    def transform(self, x: Iterable[T]) -> Iterable[T]:
        raise NotImplementedError()

class B(A):
    def transform(self, x: Iterable[str]) -> Iterable[str]:
        return [x.upper() for x in x]
```

However `mypy` says:

```
error: Argument 1 of "transform" incompatible with supertype "A"
error: Return type of "transform" incompatible with supertype "A"
```

If I remove `[T]` from `A.transform()`, then the error goes away. But that seems like the wrong solution.

After reading about [covariance and contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29), I thought that setting
`T = TypeVar('T', covariant=True)` might be a solution, but this produces the same error.

How can I fix this? I have considered binning the design altogether and replacing the A class with a higher order function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Making `T` covariant or contravariant isn't really going to help you in this case. Suppose that the code you had in your question was allowed by mypy, and suppose a user wrote the following snippet of code:

```
def uses_a_or_subclass(foo: A) -> None:
    # This is perfectly typesafe (though it'll crash at runtime)
    print(a.transform(3))

# Uh-oh! B.transform expects a str, so we just broke typesafety!
uses_a_or_subclass(B())
```

The golden rule to remember is that when you need to overwrite or redefine a function (when subclassing, like you're doing, for example), that functions are *contravariant* in parameters, and *covariant* in their return type. This means that when you're redefining a function, it's legal to make the parameters more broad/a superclass of the original parameter type, but not a subtype.

One possible fix is to make your *entire class* generic with respect to `T`. Then, instead of subclassing `A` (which is now equivalent to subclassing `A[Any]` and is probably not what you want if you'd like to stay perfectly typesafe), you'd subclass `A[str]`.

Now, your code is perfectly typesafe, and your redefined function respects function variance:

```
from typing import Iterable, TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar('T')

class A(Generic[T]):
    def transform(self, x: Iterable[T]) -> Iterable[T]:
        raise NotImplementedError()

class B(A[str]):
    def transform(self, x: Iterable[str]) -> Iterable[str]:
        return [x.upper() for x in x]
```

Now, our `uses_a_or_subclass` function from up above should be rewritten to either be generic, or to accept specifically classes that subtype `A[str]`. Either way works, depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: `Generic[T]` is bad for code that needs to support Python 2. Is there a way to fix this in a good way for Python 2?

Comment: @SebastianWagner -- can you clarify why `Generic[T]` is bad for Python-2 compatible code? I've written plenty of Python 2 code that do things like the above (after installing the 'typing' backport module via pip) and haven't run into any issues yet.

Comment: Yeah, we're not going to ship the types Backport.

Comment: @SebastianWagner -- In that case, I don't think there's really a good way forward for you here, unfortunately. Installing the 'typing' backport is the canonical and official way of bringing the full ecosystem of types to older versions of Python. If you decide against installing it, you're naturally going to run into these kinds of limitations.

Comment: What about when we want T to be B ? For example, you have a parent class A which acts as template for the methods that the Bi children should implement, and some of these are type to take elements of Bi as arguments; or are static methods that return instances of Bi. `class Bi(A[Bi])` will not work.